# Transfer requests among servers cxf

Tags: java, cxf

I see a difficult problem relating to CXF. 
My problem is described as follows:

I have two servers A and B that implement the same service.

The client sends requests (ex: 100 requests by 100 threads) to the server A at the same time. When the client receives 60 responses from the server A, the server A is suspended. So, the rest of 40 requests of client in A will be transferred to the server B. And the server B will respond the client.

Can I program a Java class to catch the rest of 40 requests of client in A and push them into B for responding the client ? Could you please give me a suggestion to implement this Java class ?

The client and the servers are implemented according to the example in http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html

Best regards,

THO

Comment: Are your request substantially time consuming?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Here, i want to stop the server A but i do not want to loss requests of clients which are waiting in A

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I don't see implementations that move an active request from one server to another.  The typical solution that I see would be:

1. Have a load balancer of some sort.
2. Have a Session management solution of some sort (such as Spring Session).  Since this operates on HttpSession, it's independent of CXF. (Trust me, you'll have state, at the very least for your security scheme.)
3. When you want to take out Server A, prevent new requests from being assigned to Server A from the load balancer.
4. When the current requests drain away, you can shut down A and do whatever you need with it.

Pros:

- Request Draining is much faster than Session Draining
- Session management solutions means no-user-downtime releases
- Session management solutions also means you don't need sticky sessions

Cons:

- Your session usage will have to be backwards compatible (at least for a release)
- If your session usage is heavy, there's an efficiency cost.
- You need to make sure that you have no long-running requests

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at wrong solution, WebServices are typically synchronous operations. By synchronous I mean to say, the webservice client sends a request and waits for the server to respond, If server doesn't respond on set timeout(in webservice client you can set connection timeout), the request is terminated with connection timeout error, or any other exception, its client to decide on the exception whether to resend the error or propagate the error to upstream systems. In your case you can resend the remaining request and use load balancer such that to routes the request to other server.

An alternative solution is to use JMS with client acknowledgement, such that requests are removed only in case the request are processed successfully. if there are any errors you don't remove the requests. In this case say suppose you suspend your server, since the processing is not successful, the messages are eligible for other servers JMS listener to process the request.

**Note:** If you already have developed webservices, CXF provides JMS Transport

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, i don't use JMS transport. I have used just UDP transport (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/udp-transport.html), this is mandatory requirement. I am a new member of CXF, so i do not understand well all technique in CXF. If possible, could you please give me more detail your solution.

Comment: Additionally, i thinks that we can set asynchronous transport between clients and server

Comment: what is the processing time of your request at server side? yes you can use asynchronous transport if processing time is long at client side so that thread could do other task in mean time

Comment: a request is sent to server, the server calculates and relpy to client. The calcul time is the processing time. I can use CXF like a black box. I don't know how to consult the arriving request in server side that have not been processed yet.